# How do I get CMake to check for TeXLive in Pandoc?

Tags: cmake, pandoc, tex-live

In PerfectTIN (https://github.com/phma/perfecttin), I build the documentation with this CMakeLists file:

```
find_program(PANDOC pandoc)

if (PANDOC)
execute_process(COMMAND ${PANDOC} "--resource-path=/" INPUT_FILE /dev/null ERROR_FILE /dev/null RESULT_VARIABLE pandoc_exit)
endif ()

if (PANDOC AND NOT pandoc_exit)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT perfecttin.pdf MAIN_DEPENDENCY perfecttin.xml COMMAND pandoc -f docbook -o perfecttin.pdf -V papersize=a4 -V margin-left=15mm -V margin-right=15mm -V margin-top=15mm -V margin-bottom=20mm --resource-path=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/perfecttin.xml)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT fileformat.pdf MAIN_DEPENDENCY fileformat.xml COMMAND pandoc -f docbook -o fileformat.pdf -V papersize=a4 -V margin-left=15mm -V margin-right=15mm -V margin-top=15mm -V margin-bottom=20mm --resource-path=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/fileformat.xml)
add_custom_target(perfecttin-doc ALL DEPENDS perfecttin.pdf fileformat.pdf)
install(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doc/fileformat.pdf ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doc/perfecttin.pdf DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/doc/perfecttin)
endif ()
```

If Pandoc is absent, it doesn't build the documentation. If Pandoc and TeXLive are both present, it builds the documentation. But if Pandoc is present but TeXLive is not, the build fails. How can I check that Pandoc has what it needs before trying to build the documentation?

I tried `"--resource-path=/ -f docbook -o /dev/zero"`; it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The program Pandoc uses is pdflatex (which is in the texlive-latex-base package in Ubuntu). So I added a search for pdflatex to CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_program(PANDOC pandoc)
find_program(PDFLATEX pdflatex)

if (PANDOC AND PDFLATEX)
execute_process(COMMAND ${PANDOC} "--resource-path=/" INPUT_FILE /dev/null ERROR_FILE /dev/null RESULT_VARIABLE pandoc_exit)
endif ()

if (PANDOC AND PDFLATEX AND NOT pandoc_exit)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT perfecttin.pdf MAIN_DEPENDENCY perfecttin.xml COMMAND pandoc -f docbook -o perfecttin.pdf -V papersize=a4 -V margin-left=15mm -V margin-right=15mm -V margin-top=15mm -V margin-bottom=20mm --resource-path=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/perfecttin.xml)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT fileformat.pdf MAIN_DEPENDENCY fileformat.xml COMMAND pandoc -f docbook -o fileformat.pdf -V papersize=a4 -V margin-left=15mm -V margin-right=15mm -V margin-top=15mm -V margin-bottom=20mm --resource-path=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/fileformat.xml)
add_custom_target(perfecttin-doc ALL DEPENDS perfecttin.pdf fileformat.pdf)
install(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doc/fileformat.pdf ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doc/perfecttin.pdf DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/doc/perfecttin)
endif ()
```